# How can I make an infinite side scrolling background in Phaserjs?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, side-scroller

I'm using phaser.js to make a game and I cannot find any tutorials on how to make the background scroll infinitely. I'd like the background to tile/repeat sideways, and infinitely as the character moves right.

I am currently using a camera and having the camera follow the character.

Here's my idea about how to do this: Check the position of the camera constantly in `update()`, and then move it to the beginning of gameplay (the very left) along with the character at that time. I think that this would probably not be a smooth transition though, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can be done with a tile sprite and by moving "tilePosition":

```
var bgtile;

function preload () {
   game.load.image('bgtile', 'bgtile.jpg');
}

function create () {
   bgtile = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, game.stage.bounds.width, game.cache.getImage('bgtile').height, 'bgtile');
}

function update () {
   bgtile.tilePosition.x -= 1;
}
```

Comment: As the update() function uses positioning, won't this be a bit vulnerable if the FPS is unstable? When one gives an object velocity the speed should be more steady. What would be a good way of doing this with a tiled background?