# moving background in phaser

Tags: html, phaser-framework

i am trying to move the background when pressing the left button, i am using phaser and here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>hello phaser!</title>
        <script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
                    preload : preload,
                    create : create,
                    update : update
                });
                var score = 0;
                var scoreText;

                function preload() {
                    game.load.image('sky', 'sky.png');
                }

                function create() {
                    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
                    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');   
                }

                function update() {
                    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
                    if (cursors.left.isDown) {

                        sky.body.velocity.x = -150;
                    } 

                }   

            };

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

when i run it nothing happen to the background and i do not know where is the problem

Comment: Hey can you complet a jsfiddle ? i started one here : http://jsfiddle.net/g10ws4ad/

Comment: i write the code in an html file, there is no css
all i have in the game folder is phaser.min.js and the images

Comment: i found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669312/phaser-js-infinite-side-scrolling-background)

Answer (score 2):

Glad you've found the answer already, but just to add that this line:

```
cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
```

should *not* be in the *update* function. It should be set just once in *create*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has **3 errors** at least.

1. you have no variant named "sky"

   so, use

   `sky = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');`

   instead of

   `game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');`
2. create cursors should be in create function , not update function.

   `cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();`
3. you should enable physics for sprite manually. by default, sprite has no physics.

   `game.physics.enable(sky, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);`

**runable js code likes this:**

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload : preload,
    create : create,
    update : update
});
var sky;
var cursors;

function preload() {
    game.load.image('sky', 'sky.png');
}

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    sky = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');   
    game.physics.enable(sky, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update() {
    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        sky.body.velocity.x = -150;
    } else {
        sky.body.velocity.x = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this out now.

```
var background;
    function create() {
        background = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, this.game.width, this.game.height, 'sky');
        background.fixedToCamera = true;
    }


        function update() {
            if (cursors.left.isDown) {
                background.tileposition.x = -150;
            }
    }
```

Although -150 may be too large :)

[See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669312/phaser-js-infinite-side-scrolling-background)