# Continuously scrolling background?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Pretty self explanatory, I have an image I want to use for a background and I want it to continuously scroll and repeat itself.  I found some code in this question

[Phaser.js - Infinite side scrolling background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669312/phaser-js-infinite-side-scrolling-background)

and applied it like so

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
});

var bgtile;

function preload() {
    game.load.image('bgtile', 'riverTest.jpg');
}


function create() {
    bgtile = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0,
                 game.stage.bounds.width,
                 game.cache.getImage('bgtile').height,
                 'bgtile');
}

function update() {
    bgtile.tilePosition.x -= 1;
}
```

The image riverTest.jpg is stored in my assets folder however, when I run this it just shows a black screen.  Any idea what's going on?  I'm very new to Phaser JS so any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Didn't think to check the console for whatever reason, but I was getting two errors

Line 27(the create function): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Line 31(the update function): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tilePosition' of undefined

Comment: What is your directory structure like.  Where is your game js located?  Is it in root, and your image in assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switch

```
game.stage.bounds.width
```

to

```
game.stage.getBounds.width
```

Comment: I was apparently getting errors in the console I didn't think of looking at.  I edited the question with the errors included

Comment: @Joris , I tested your code and it works... Again are you running this on a web server?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on wamp

Comment: What version of phaser are you using?

Comment: I'm running version 2.2.2

Comment: Thank you!  I've been searching for a solution but it's very inconclusive.  It seems to just work for some people and not for others

Comment: @Joris look at my edited post.  Apparently its no longer bounds its getBounds

Comment: That did it!  Thank you!

Comment: If you still happen to be around, the image only occupies about 1/3 of the screen but does scroll.  Any idea why that would be?